# Setting and saving a password with Shared Preferences

Tags: android, if-statement, passwords, sharedpreferences

I want to create an app which will save a password for the next time the user wants to use this app. I've got my If-statements working, but the password doesn't want to save. This is for an assignment, and I've tried some stuff but nothing seems to work. Please help!

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WheresMyPhoneActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Button start;
    private EditText pword;
    private EditText confirm;
    SharedPreferences myFolder; 
    public final String filename = "PasswordFile";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        confirm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtConfirm);
        myFolder = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

        start.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String pass = pword.getText().toString();
            String conf = confirm.getText().toString();

            //Check that user typed in a password
            if(pass.length()<6){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Password must be at least 6     characters long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pword.setText("");
                confirm.setText("");
                pword.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            //Make sure two fields match
            if(pass.equals(conf)){
                //fields match, store configuration in shared preferences
                Editor passwdfile = getSharedPreferences("passwd", 0).edit();
                passwdfile.putString("passwd",pass);
                passwdfile.commit();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(WheresMyPhoneActivity.this, Home.class));

            }else{//password mismatch - start over
                Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords must match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pword.setText("");
                confirm.setText("");
                pword.requestFocus();
                return;
            }

}
```

Comment: `...but the password doesn't want to save.`. So what does it say ? How do you know it doesn't save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't missmatch your shared preferences filename ?
I can see you have a `myFolder = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);` where `filename = "PasswordFile"`.   In the other hand, you save the password to another shared preferences file named `passwd` : `getSharedPreferences("passwd", 0)`.

If you don't have specific need to work with several shared preferences files, I would suggest you to use the default instance of shared preferences of your app : `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`